# Upgrade from Windows 7 Starter to Windows 7 Ultimate troubles

Tags: windows-7, windows

I run the any time upgrade feature in Windows Starter, the upgrade was completed and needed the netbook to restart.  Once it restarted a black window appeared saying that the computer was not able to restart.  I wasted a lot of time and tried it twice thinking that I had made a mistake during the upgrade process.  Any ideas on how I can get to work properly?

Comment: Can you more precisely describe the error message? What was the exact message? What happened right before the message popped up? How much of the boot process completed?

Comment: If the system wouldn't restart, how did you try it the 2nd time?